# Security for API using Sitecore JSS

Tags: api, security, sitecore

I have created a Sitecore JSS app. I can access data from Sitecore in it.
It is possible to access data on an HTML page via API (layout service) URL what
gives a JSON result. My API like this:

`/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item="Path/GUID"&sc_apikey="apikey"`

I want to add some level of security to my API, I looked for options, but couldn't get any specific solution.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Comment: What type of security do you want to have? This question needs some more details for somebody to help you.

Comment: Security like username and password to set for api

Comment: Are you wanting this for end user authentication to content? Do you want to have application-level security for which apps can invoke the API? Are you wanting to authenticate current context against Sitecore based on the user visiting your JSS site?